# Error when making form! Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /srv/disk6/1346207/www/standingroomonly.co.nf/form.php on line 18

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I get this error when trying to make a form:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /srv/disk6/1346207/www/standingroomonly.co.nf/form.php on line 18
```

when I use this php:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'myname');
define('DB_USER', 'myuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_HOST', 'myhost');

$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_selected_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error())
}

$value = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close();
?>
```

As you can see, I am trying to transfer what is in the name text box to mySQL database. But the error appears when i press submit!
Please help!

Comment: *warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: an extra semicolon after `die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error())` would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot `;` after `mysql_error())`

replace

`if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error())
}`

with

`if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: thank you! but now it says Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_selected_db() in /srv/disk6/1346207/www/standingroomonly.co.nf/form.php on line 14

Comment: @findavcol it is NOT `mysql_selected_db()` it IS `mysql_select_db()`